# Adding a class to body when a Hyperlink tag is clicked which is in the child ul of li tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a class to body when a link is clicked. This is easily done when the link is in the parent ul, but my problem is that i want to do that for the the link present in the child ul of parent li. Whenever I try to do this It  has no effect.
What I am trying to do is as given below:
Script:

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul.treeview-menu").find("a.links").click(function () {
            $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
         });
      });
   </script>

 <ul class="sidebar-menu nav nav-list" id="dashboard-menu">
    <li class="treeview">
         <a rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" target="_self" href="">
             <span class="caption">Parent Link</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
               <li>
                     <a href="any-link" target="_self" class="links">child link</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
 <ul>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is problem? It work in https://jsfiddle.net/sxmbbu2d/

Comment: Just use this `$("ul ul a.links").click()`

Comment: syntax error ?  line 4 `//});` closing parentheses commented ?

Comment: `$("ul ul a.links").click()` works as well

Comment: The problem in your code is the **`href="abc"`**. Change this to say "#" or so, it should work like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `on('click',...)`, may be your Navigation will generate dynamically after load page so you have to use delegated event binding

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','ul.treeview-menu a.links',function () {
        $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
    });
  });



<ul class="sidebar-menu nav nav-list" id="dashboard-menu">
    <li class="treeview">
         <a rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" target="_self" href="">
             <span class="caption">Parent Link</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
               <li>
                     <a href="abc" target="_self" class="links">child link</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
 <ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, I am please to help you... dont forget to give up vote also. :)

Comment: Thank you, Your answer solved my problem. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

you have two issues:

1- this line  //}); it was commented and was preventing your code from working.

2-when the hyperlink is clicked it refreshes the page and thus any class you've added to your previous html has been erased that's why you want be able to see any change.

try this:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("ul.treeview-menu").find("a.links").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
            $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
        });
      });
   </script>

 <ul class="sidebar-menu nav nav-list" id="dashboard-menu">
    <li class="treeview">
         <a rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" target="_self" href="">
             <span class="caption">Parent Link</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
               <li>
                     <a href="abc" target="_self" class="links">child link</a>
               </li>
          </ul>
    </li>
 <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.treeview-menu").find("a.links").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
        $("body").addClass("Enter your class name");
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".